# Renaming txt file using data in text file

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, rename, mac-address

My first post so please be gentle.

I have batch file that outputs ipconfig/all data to a txt file on my desktop.

Is it possible to use the ip address or mac address data contained in the file to reanme the file.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

First you need to find the address. E.g. with

```
findstr /C:"  IPv6 Address" foo.txt
```

Then you need to get the address into a variable:

```
set Address=
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr /C:"  IPv6 Address" foo.txt') do (
  if not defined Address=%%b
)
```

Note the use of `%%b` there, despite the loop variable being `%%a`. That's because tokenization creates new variables. Also we're only using the first address because there might be several, but that's only a vague heuristic because it's not really set in stone whether non-NIC devices come before or after them.

Then we need to clean up the address because colons are not valid in file names:

```
set Address=%Address::=_%
```

And rename the file

```
ren foo.txt %Address%.txt
```

You surely can figure out how to adapt this to IPv4 or MAC addresses, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Joey. Sorry if I'm being a bit thick but how do I add this code to my bat file "ipconfig /all >"

Comment: You said, you already have a batch file that outputs that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to select the MAC address you need, if you adjust the terms.

At the moment it picks the first Ethernet device it finds in the `ipconfig /all` output and creates a txt file with the MAC address.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ipconfig /all ^|findrepl "Ethernet" /e:"Physical Address" /b:"Physical Address" ^|findrepl ".*Physical Address.*: (.*)" "$1" ^|findrepl /o:1:1 ') do (
ipconfig /all >"%%a.txt"
)
```

The above uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.